# How to disable an alias in bash for a single command?

Tags: bash, alias

Let's say you leave your terminal open and a co-worker comes along and types:

```
alias    exit='echo nope'
alias unalias='echo nope'
alias    type='echo nope'
alias builtin='echo nope'
alias   alias='echo nope'
```

How could you run one of these commands anyway?

Comment: Also (a little later) [Temporarily disabling an alias / quoting a word with a backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162903/temporarily-disabling-an-alias-quoting-a-word-with-a-backslash)

Comment: @ThomasDickey, if you can manage to switch it around so my "OP's dupe close button" shows the second link above, I'll accept the dupe close.

Comment: The system allows only one vote, and I cited the earlier one first for the usual reasons (it applies to `bash` as well).

Comment: There's an question about quote part of command name recently, I can not find it yet.

Comment: @Wildcard the second link can't be used to close this question as a dupe anyway, because it's on stackoverflow.com, not U&L.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method I'm aware of for doing this is to preface the command with a backslash:

```
$ type type
nope type
$ \type type
type is aliased to `echo nope'
$ unalias type
nope type
$ \type unalias
unalias is aliased to `echo nope'
$ \unalias unalias
$ unalias type
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type unalias
unalias is a shell builtin
$
```

I don't know where this is documented, however.

Comment: The man bash said: The characters /, $, `, and = and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an alias name. 
 There are three quoting mechanisms: the escape character, single quotes, and double quotes.